# Why DataTables not clear custom state?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I can't find an answer to such a question. I save custom state in the data object:

```
"stateSaveParams": function (settings, data) {
            var temp = {};
            jQuery('#userForm input.input-filter').each(function() {
                temp[ jQuery(this).attr('placeholder') ] = this.value;
            });
            data.colsFilter = temp;
            ... 
}
```

They are cleared by the state.clear() method, ("This method will trigger a DataTables state save but with an empty object (i.e. {}"), effectively erasing any existing state data.) but after the state expires (for example: "stateDuration": 50) only the standard DataTables values are reset to default, but my personal ones are not. Did someone have a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer to my question here: [link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43870/why-datatables-not-clear-custom-state#latest)